# How to optimize my query so that I can use ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I use `ORDER BY` in the below query but it takes the almost 20 sec to fetch the data.

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       o.map.subject, 
       o.map.xyz 
FROM   student o 
WHERE  test = 3553 
       AND o.map.identifier = 'Abhay' 
ORDER  BY o.id desc 
FETCH first 15 ROWS only;
```

When do not use `ORDER BY`, as shown below, it takes only the 0.2 sec response time which is what I want. The problem is - it is fetching the older data, I need to get the last 15 records inserted into the table student.

Is there any way to sort the data without using `ORDER BY`? If not, how can I speed up the  query?

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       o.map.subject, 
       o.map.xyz 
FROM   student o 
WHERE  test = 3553 
       AND o.map.identifier = 'Abhay' 
FETCH first 15 ROWS only;
```

Comment: Check out [Indexes and Index-Organized Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/CNCPT/indexiot.htm#CNCPT721)

Comment: @Brien is this a only way ?

Comment: It seems strange to me that Students would have so many records (tens of millions) in the first place to warrant this performance. Take a look at that link and maybe someone else will provide a real answer to you. I am just pointing out indexes in case you are inexperienced and hadn’t worked with them.

Comment: Try to use WHERE **ROWNUM <= 15** instead to **FETCH first 15 ROWS only;** your query will be something like :

`SELECT id, 
       name, 
       o.map.subject, 
       o.map.xyz 
FROM   student o 
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 15
       AND test = 3553 
       AND o.map.identifier = 'Abhay'
ORDER  BY o.id desc;`

Comment: @KortebyFarouk Using  WHERE ROWNUM <= 15 ORDER BY ID DESC will not return the top rows (as defined by ID).  You will get a random set of rows.

Comment: The **only** way to get a guaranteed sort order is to use `order by`. **Nothing** else will result in a predictable sort order.

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald there is ORDER BY in the query so you will get the top rows

Comment: @KortebyFarouk  Simple demonstration here https://connor-mcdonald.com/2018/02/28/rownum-and-order-by/

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald tank you for the demonstration i learned something new

Comment: @KortebyFarouk My pleasure.  Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

The query

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       o.map.subject, 
       o.map.xyz 
FROM   student o 
WHERE  test = 3553 
       AND o.map.identifier = 'Abhay' 
ORDER  BY o.id desc 
FETCH first 15 ROWS only;
```

only runs slowly if either it is expensive to *find* the rows, or we get a huge number of rows and hence it is expensive to *sort* them.

If it is expensive to find then, then you probably need to consider indexing on TEST,MAP_IDENTIFIER.  If, even with that index, the sorting cost is large, that is, you have a huge amount of rows that match the criteria, then you might want to consider adding ID to the index so that you can scan the index in a descending fashion and hence avoid the sorting cost.

Even if you do that, you **must** always have the ORDER BY clause.  Without out, the results are always indeterminate.